# Call Js lib from typescript file withou .d.ts

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'd like to use a javascript lib that provide controls in my typescript projet but there is no definition in typescript or .d.ts for this lib.
Is it possible ?

So let me rectify i want to use the devexpress library dashboard viewer 
https://documentation.devexpress.com/Dashboard/119108/Building-the-Designer-and-Viewer-Applications/Web-Dashboard/HTML-JavaScript-Dashboard-Control
https://documentation.devexpress.com/Dashboard/119158/Building-the-Designer-and-Viewer-Applications/Web-Dashboard/HTML-JavaScript-Dashboard-Control/Client-Side-Configuration-Global-Namespaces

But in the typescript.d.ts from the devexpress group their is no control planned for using this function

```
DevExpress.Dashboard.ResourceManager.embedBundledResources();
// Creates a new Web Dashboard control with the specified ID and settings:
var dashboardControl = new DevExpress.Dashboard.DashboardControl(document.getElementById("container"), {
    // Configures an URL where the Web Dashboard's server-side is hosted:
    endpoint: "https://demos.devexpress.com/services/dashboard/api",
    workingMode: "Viewer",
    extensions: {
        "dashboard-panel": (control) => new DevExpress.Dashboard.DashboardPanelExtension(control)
    }
});
```

That i'd like to use in my typescript file so it's not recognized even if the javascript is loaded in my html file

Thx in advance,
Razgort

Comment: What is the problem in my question ?

Comment: Low quality question: no code, no error message, no indication of own research effort.

Comment: i edited the question to provide more informations sorry

Comment: Have you tried to copy the existing `typescript.d.ts` into your project, thus overriding the one from the module, and adding the missing API yourself?

Comment: How can i  add the missing controls ? i've never done any typescript .d.ts

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by running the command `npm i @types/knockout`

Comment: a suggestion - install `@types` as `--save-dev`. or dev dependencies. You generally dont need it at run time